# Can I change dyanmic javascript variable depending on user form input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My question here is if there is a way to change the dynamic price calculation depending on the name a user enters in the input field.

I have code that works very well for calculating a dynamic price in an html form. Here is the code:

Using this input:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="Amount"/>
```

My Javascript then calculates price:

```
jQuery("input[name='Amount']").change(function () {
if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)) || !isFinite(this.value)) {
    jQuery(this).val('');
    return false;
}
var calc = parseFloat(this.value) * 0.95;
jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc);
});
```

That by itself works fantastic. It calculates the amount by .95 and then assigns that value as price.

If I add this into the form:

```
<input class="stores typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Stores" name="name"/>
```

What can I do here to be able to calculate the price at different values depending on the store name. For example, if someone enters McDonalds, I want it to calculate at .90. If someone enters Target, I want it to calculate at .92. The previous javascript cannot accomplish this because it calculates everything at .95 instead of being able to change depending on the store entered.

I would prefer to accomplish this with javascript because I'm not very skilled with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Javascript object for this.

```
var stores = {
     "McDonalds" : .90,
     "Target" : .92,
}
var storeName = jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='name']").val();
console.log(stores[storeName]); //Output the store cost to console.
```

Though I think the jQuery lookup function is questionable. I'm sure there is a better way to select that textbox. But that's the general concept you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Not sure why someone came on here and hit -1, I thought my question was pretty clear. And you answered it perfectly.

Comment: you would use the `stores[storeName]` instead of the current number you're using (0.95). I suggest you learn a bit more on basics of Javascript as it seems like you're pretty new to it.